# SQL Server 2012 CU7 for SP3 download link pls..?

Tags: sql-server-2012

Am unable to download CU7 for SQL 2012 SP3. Can anybody provide link to download CU7 for SQL Server 2012 SP3...? I don't need latest CU9..

SQL Server services running with CU7 but SSRS services still running on SP3, we are facing bit mapping issue, to fix this we need to apply CU7 on SSRS.

Comment: Use Brent Ozar's https://sqlserverupdates.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Cumulative Update 7 for SQL Server 2012 SP3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3205051/cumulative-update-7-for-sql-server-2012-sp3)

Comment: The link prompting to download CU9(Latest), not CU7

Comment: Ok, I'll try to post it without hiding in tag: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3205051/cumulative-update-7-for-sql-server-2012-sp3

Comment: But I tried 2 times and it opens Cumulative Update 7 for SQL Server 2012 SP3, or it's only the name of KB article and then it offer you CU9 to download?

Comment: I believe Microsoft recommending to apply latest CU, not specified CU.. ! All the CU links prompting to Latest CU only. I do not find the link to download specified CU for SQL..

Comment: Now I understand, I see it clicking the button and even if KB article is about CU7, it offers to download only the latest CU

Comment: I tried to get help from support via chat but no luck... Finally I found the link from the spicewroks. here it is http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb3205051

Comment: Yes you are right, some rows below the download button i found this: Note After future cumulative updates are released for SQL Server 2012 SP3, this CU can be located and downloaded from the Microsoft Windows Update Catalog. However, Microsoft recommends that you install the latest cumulative update available.

Comment: So they "recommends" without any other choice: the Update Catalog contains the CUs up to 5 only

Comment: Yeah, They recommended and pushing to apply latest CU only :-) . Its very hard to find the links. very few only knows about catalog search. Today I came to know new search for KB article :-)